# Persisting session variables in Machine learning server

Tags: r, web-services, microsoft-r, r-server

I am new to R server and I am starting to publish my functions as web services which is working fine. The problem is that they all work with a big data.table and I want to avoid having to send it (or read it from the DB) in each request. How can I keep variables in memory, once loaded, in Microsoft R server (now Machine Learning Server)?